# Error insert a value into a list-Python

Tags: python, list, constructor, insert

I want to insert an object into a list and I gives me an error saying:

```
    Archive.insertdoc(d)
TypeError: insertdoc() missing 1 required positional argument: 'd'
```

This is in my Main module:

```
doc = Document(name, author, file)
Archive.insertdoc(doc)
```

`Archive` module:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.listdoc = []

def insertdoc(self, d):
    self.listdoc.append(d)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an *instance* of the `Archive` class; you are accessing the unbound method instead.

This should work:

```
archive = Archive()

doc = Document(name, author, file)
archive.insertdoc(doc)
```

This assumes you have:

```
class Archive():
    def __init__(self):
        self.listdoc = []

    def insertdoc(self, d):
        self.listdoc.append(d)
```

If you put two functions at *module level* instead, you cannot have a `self` reference in a function and have it bind to the module; functions are not bound to modules.

If your archive is supposed to be a global to your application, create a single instance of the `Archive` class in the module instead, and use that one instance only.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `Archive.insertdoc` is an instance method of the class `Archive`.  Meaning, it must be invoked on an instance of `Archive`:

```
doc = Document(name, author, file)
archive = Archive()     # Make an instance of class Archive
archive.insertdoc(doc)  # Invoke the insertdoc method of that instance
```